# Elixir Phoenix: How to get 500 error information and notify admins

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to get a telegram message / email whenever one of my customers manages to create a server error. Because that usually means that we created a bug and need to fix it asap.
I also want the customers to be able to go back to where they came from, so I want to display a javascript go back button.

How do I go about that?

The button could look something like this:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Back</button>
```

And notifying the admins like this:

```
for id <- Application.get_env(:nadia, :admin_chat_ids) do
  message = "#{error information like stacktrace and user information}"
  Nadia.send_message(id, message)
end
```

Where can I override the default behavior of phoenix and get the necessary information?

Comment: You could use something like Sentry (https://sentry.io/for/elixir/)? With regards to the back button, are you after information on how to create a custom error page (https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/custom_error_pages.html#content)?

Comment: Do I need to use an external paid service like sentry or rollbar or similar for that?

Comment: you can use free plan on rollbar for example

Comment: Sentry has a free tier - which is ideal while you're creating your site. I haven't tested the boundaries of the free tier - I don't have many users! But I'm assuming you could gain paying customers to cover the cost of the next tier before you actually need it

Answer (score 2):

You can use rollbar for example, it will send emails every-time you get new error, or repeatedly error, you can configure it on there UI.

in order to connect rollbar to your phoenix application, you would need [rollbax](https://github.com/ForzaElixir/rollbax) gem it is wrapper for elixir library.

installation

```rb
defp deps() do
  [{:rollbax, ">= 0.0.0"}]
end
```

And add to your config. Your token will be available through the site after you create project.

```rb
config :rollbax,
  access_token: "YOUR_TOKEN",
  environment: "production"
```

And for using it inside Phoenix you would need to use it as `Plug`

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use Plug.Router # or `use MyApp.Web, :router` for Phoenix apps
  use Plug.ErrorHandler

  defp handle_errors(conn, %{kind: kind, reason: reason, stack: stacktrace}) do
    Rollbax.report(kind, reason, stacktrace)
  end
end
```

[Phoenix rollbax configuration](https://hexdocs.pm/rollbax/using-rollbax-in-plug-based-applications.html)